# No me reconoce las entidades al cambiar de versión de Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo algunos proyectos hechos en Java 8 y Spring Boot 2.7.15, que funcionan bien.
Aquí un ejemplo de clase principal, entidad y repositorio:

Clase principal:

```
package com.yomatias.historiamundiales;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HistoriaMundialesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HistoriaMundialesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Entidad:

```
package com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "paises")
public class Pais {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pais")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name = "continente")
    private String continente;
    
}
```

---

Repositorio:

```
package com.yomatias.historiamundiales.repositorios;

import com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades.Pais;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PaisRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Pais, String> {
    
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Pais p")
    public List<Pais> listarPaises();
    
}
```

---

Como decía, funcionan bien en Java 8 con Spring Boot 2.7.15. El problema es que al querer actualizarlo a Java 17 y Spring Boot 3.1.3, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-16T09:55:42.342+02:00 ERROR 10404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'paisController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'paisRepositorio': Error creating bean with name 'paisRepositorio' defined in com.yomatias.historiamundiales.repositorios.PaisRepositorio defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades.Pais
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:716) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:696) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.yomatias.historiamundiales.HistoriaMundialesApplication.main(HistoriaMundialesApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'paisRepositorio' defined in com.yomatias.historiamundiales.repositorios.PaisRepositorio defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades.Pais
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades.Pais
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

---

He intentado corregirlo añadiendo la anotación `@EntityScan` a la clase principal. En este caso:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades")
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar.

Con otras entidades del mismo proyecto y con otros proyectos me sucede lo mismo.
¿Alguna idea de dónde puede estar el problema? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Spring Boot 3 la versión base de Spring y de sus distintos módulos se actualizaron. Ahora en vez de usar los espacios de nombre `javax` (Java EE), usan `jakarta` (Jakarta EE), una especificación abierta y prácticamente igual, pero mantenida por una comunidad abierta en vez de por Oracle.

Por tanto, al usar JPA hay que usar `jakarta.persistence`, con lo que tenemos que remplazarlos en las distintas entidades, repositorios y demás sitios donde se acceda.

Por tanto, la entidad país quedaría tal que:

```java
package com.yomatias.historiamundiales.entidades;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "paises")
public class Pais {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pais")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name = "continente")
    private String continente; 
}
```

Como consejo, si usas IntelliJ IDEA, puedes usar la [herramienta de remplazo global](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#replace_search_string_in_project) para buscar en todo el proyecto `javax.persistence` y remplazar por `jakarta.persistence`.